# Changing Background of One Page on Squarespace

Tags: css, squarespace

I am trying to change the background on the Blog page of my website. The current website is all black backgrounds, but I would like the Blog page to be white with black text. I need to have my own CSS as Squarespace does not support this as a custom setting.

I have already tried codes provided for things like this, but nothing has worked. For instance: https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/14800/how-can-i-change-the-content-background-color-on-only-one-page-using-css.html

#main { background-color: #ffffff; }

I would like the background color to change.

Comment: Could you provide the name of the template you are using, and (even better), a link to the site/page in question (yoursite.squarespace.com/yourpage) along with the view-only password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may target the blog specifically via its collection ID, which Squarespace adds as a class for you, on the `body` element. From there, we must target the `div` that is its immediate child, `.overflow-wrapper`.

Insert the following CSS via the CSS Editor:

```
.collection-5d0a3c81de1f2b00012ccccc .overflow-wrapper {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Because the text is white, it will appear invisible. You should be able to adjust the titles and other meta-information (author, date, tags, categories, etc.) using the Style Editor.

However, I don't believe the style editor will give you an option to alter the body text (`p` elements) on the blog separately from the rest of the site. Therefore you may also find the following CSS helpful for changing body text on blog pages to black:

```
.collection-5d0a3c81de1f2b00012ccccc p {
  color: black;
}
```

In addition, you may need to add some CSS to address the header, which as a result of setting a white background will be unreadable.

```
.collection-5d0a3c81de1f2b00012ccccc.site-spacing-small .site-header, .site-spacing-small .site-page, .site-spacing-small .site-footer {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 3vw;
  padding-bottom: 3vw;
}

.collection-5d0a3c81de1f2b00012ccccc #header {
  background-color: black;
}
```

And finally, the page title should also be set to black:

```
.collection-5d0a3c81de1f2b00012ccccc .page-text-wrapper .page-title {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! Is there any way to change the navigation primary color just on that page as well? The issue is that now the nav. menu is not visible on the white background on the blog page.

Comment: I would suggest instead keeping the navigation background color black, because I think that will be more reliable for subnavigation and such. It's also more consistent with the mobile navigation that way. I've updated the answer above. Note that I also updated the second code snippet that was in the original answer, adding `p`, which was intended to be in the original answer. Finally, don't forget to mark the correct answer as the accepted answer, if it answers your question.